# how to inject Test-Implementation during tests, Production-Implementation in the production mode - Spring, JSR-330

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, inject, jsr330

Lets assume that I have sequencer and the following Beans. Sequencer is responsible for taking the next value from a database sequence. 
OracleSequencer is used in the production mode, TestSequencer during JUnit-Tests.

```
public interface Sequencer{
  long getNextValue();
}

@Named("OracleSequencer")
public class OracleSequencer implements Sequencer[
...
}

@Named("TestSequencer")
public class TestSequencer implements Sequencer[
...
}
```

And this is how I want to use it:

```
@Named
public class BusinessBean{
  @Inject
  private Sequencer sequencer;
}
```

**My problem is**:
When I run the app in the production mode I want to inject *OracleSequencer* in **BusinessBean**, when I run JUnit-Test I want to inject *TestSequencer*. Is it possible with JSR-330 (@Inject, @Named) ?

I found 2 dirty solutions:

- at the begining of a test, Sequencer can be replaced in the bean, which is taken from Spring-ApplicationContext. It is possible when prototype is appropriate and TestSequencer doesnt have any other dependencies:

  BusinessBean bean = springContext.getBean(..);
   bean.setSequencer(new TestSequencer());
- We can annotate OracleSequencer with @ProductionScope and TestSequencer with @TestScope and configure Spring that he scans appropiate annotations in the appropriate mode.

Do you have maybe any other idea how to solve this problem?

Spring 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use Spring Profiles introduced with Spring 3.1, essentially define a profile named "prod" and "test", let your `OracleSequencer` be created in `prod` profile and `TestSequencer` in `test` profile.

For your test, activate the `test` profile alone, and your prod activate the `prod` profile.

Here is one reference to Profiles - http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/

Another solution like you suggested will be to override your `sequencer` bean in test with the `TestSequencer`, either by specifying a bean with the exact same name as your prod sequencer or specifying it in a new application context which is imported in test mode.